# Muslim immigration bans: if a Muslim is asked "are you a Muslim" should they nevertheless say "yes"?

Tags: taqiya

One version of [Donald Trump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Trump)'s proposed immigration policies involves banning Muslim immigration from the USA:

> **One of Trump's most controversial proposals was his original plan for a "total and complete" temporary ban on foreign Muslims entering the United States.** Trump later changed his position by stating that the temporary ban would apply only to people originating from countries with a "proven history of terrorism against the United States or its allies", or countries "compromised by terrorism".

In Australian politics, we have a similar call from Senator [Pauline Hanson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauline_Hanson):

> After the 2016 Orlando nightclub shooting, Hanson posted a video on her Facebook page **calling for a ban on Muslim immigration to Australia**.

How could this be implemented?

> Trump... has suggested that customs agents ask, "Are you a Muslim?" and turn away those who say yes. -- [NewsMax](http://www.newsmax.com/Headline/Immigration-Experts-Trump-Muslim-Ban/2016/08/03/id/741951/)

Which leads me to my question:

**Question**: In the context of Muslim immigration bans, it would be desirable for a Muslim to momentarily deny being a Muslim.  If a Muslim is asked "are you a Muslim" should they nevertheless say "yes"?

I'd guess terrorists would have no qualms about lying to get through immigration.  But what about the good Muslims?  I personally would be unwilling to lie.  Playing a role are:

- [Taqiya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taqiya), which Wikipedia describes as "denial of religious belief and practice in the face of persecution":

  > Whoever disbelieves in Allah after his belief... except for one who is forced [to renounce his religion] while his heart is secure in faith. But those who [willingly] open their breasts to disbelief, upon them is wrath from Allah, and for them is a great punishment -- [Qur'an 16:106](https://quran.com/16:106)

  While negatives, being denied entry into the USA or Australia arguably does not seem sufficient to consider it as being "forced".  So, by this logic, a Muslim should say "yes" and accept they're literally "going back to where they came from".

  In fact, it may be that responding "no" could be interpreted as [apostasy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostasy_in_Islam), although they could repent after getting through immigration.  (And, technically, immigration wouldn't be letting in Muslims.)
- The Qur'an forbids (or, at least, strongly discourages) lying:

  > Then whoever argues with you about it after [this] knowledge has come to you - say, "Come, let us call our sons and your sons, our women and your women, ourselves and yourselves, then supplicate earnestly [together] **and invoke the curse of Allah upon the liars [among us].**" -- [Qur'an 3:61](https://quran.com/3:61)
  >
  > Unquestionably, for Allah is the pure religion. And those who take protectors besides Him [say], "We only worship them that they may bring us nearer to Allah in position." Indeed, Allah will judge between them concerning that over which they differ. **Indeed, Allah does not guide he who is a liar and [confirmed] disbeliever**. -- [Qur'an 39:3](https://quran.com/39:3)

Comment: I'm not sure what sort of answer your looking for, the verses you provided clearly answer your question. Furthermore, if any muslim freely and willingly decides to go to a foreign country then he has to agree with their terms. the question should be should a muslim go and not should he lie to go

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This verse explains itself.

> Verily! As for those whom the angels take (in death) while they are wronging themselves (as they stayed among the disbelievers even though emigration was obligatory for them), they (angels) say (to them): "In what (condition) were you?" They reply: "We were weak and oppressed on earth." They (angels) say: "Was not the earth of Allah spacious enough for you to emigrate therein?" Such men will find their abode in Hell - What an evil destination! 4:97

As I said in the comments, a Muslim who freely and willingly enters a foreign country is obviously agreeing to their terms. We shouldn't seek a reason to lie to get an entry and put our beliefs on the line.

In a more explicit way, "taqya" doesn't even apply in this case as **this is not a Life threatening situation in the first place.**

**Lying to get through an airport is as equal to lying to get a personal interest from someone.** The judgement is to God.

Comment: Thank you!  While Qur'an 4:97 is [interpreted](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=90891) as meaning not to reside among disbelievers who inhibit the practice of Islam, I feel it's applicable to the immigration case too.  The [Qur'an continues](https://quran.com/4:98) "...Except for the oppressed among men, women and children who cannot devise a plan nor are they directed to a way..."  Which indicates that one should be proactive (i.e., "devise a plan") in avoiding oppression (in this case, don't go to the USA/Australia).

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones now one should add. If the person at the airport is lying due to being afraid of his life, then it's possible. But if the lie is just because the person think it's an opportunity for personal interest then it is not OK. For instance if a syrian reached to america, he might be able to lie if he have good reasons to believe he will be sent back to the syrian war (and die). If he have good reasons to believe he might be sent to another country where his life isn't treated, then again it's not ok to lie.

Comment: Even the syrian example is a little bit off. The closest safe place (and muslim friendly) is not even america. Lol.

Comment: What I am trying to say, it is the intention that counts. Maybe the person didn't know that he would be questioned when he arrived to America. He might not have known that he might have been sent back.

Comment: Exactly what I'm trying to say. A syrian going all the way to america "looking for a safe place" could have found it a lot more closer to Syria. Which would question on his intention thus why I believe your example is off. I'll stop it right here as they might delete everything I say, again.

Comment: It is not illegal to try to go to a safer place which is more economical stable than a closer place. But if he has to lie to get there, of course then he should choose another place. But if he didn't know about that he would be questioned, and have good reasons to believe that he is going to be sent back (and not get secure), then I believe he can lie.

Answer (score 1):

**The short answer to this is yes and no.** It depends. All situations should be analysed individually.

I agree with what @cerberus23 stated, but I just want to add some details.

> **4:97**
>   Surely (as for) those whom the angels cause to die while they are unjust to their souls, they shall say: In what state were you? They shall say: **We were weak in the earth**. They shall say: **Was not Allah's earth spacious, so that you should have migrated therein?** So these it is whose abode is hell, and it is an evil resort

Now this verse is speaking about people in a place where they are being oppressed, and likely forbidden to follow their religion (Islam), which indirectly makes them sin or do "unjust", it is also **directed to people who has the possibility or ability** to move to another place where they won't be oppressed any more.

Now the verse after continues:

> Except the weak from among the men and the children who have not in their power the means nor can they find a way (to escape);

If a person doesn't have the possibility to move they are not to be blamed. [The intention is very important.](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/1/1)

Now, the one that has the possibility to move **isn't** bound or limited to travel to the nearest safest place and might have several reasons why he wants to travel a bit farer away *(he might have his family there for instance, he might understand the language, he might have good indications that he will be able to provide for his family there and so on)*.  Also consider "ardo Allahi wasi'aton", "inna ardi wasi'aton faiyyaya fa'abodoni" (God's earth is wide)

If we assume that it becomes a rule in America that whoever enters the borders as an immigrate, must answer whether or not they are a Muslim, if they are, they get kicked out! **In this situation it is very hard to say if the person is excused to lie or not.** I will list cases where it is *arguable* that he can lie:

- His life or someone else life is in danger
- He can't know for sure if he will be sent to a safer place
- All his family lives there
- If he is sent to another place, he knows for sure he will do much more sin *(in comparison to a white lie it's a drop in the ocean)*. How can he know? No family to stop him, no muslim friends, no language, no job opportunity and so on ...
- He didn't know in the first place that after going a so long trip, he would be sent away just because of a believe

But then again, these points are all exceptions. One might ask, how good will a life be in a country which wants to send me away just because I am Muslim? There again, is it better than the war zone you came from?

Also the verses about lies you have quoted is in another context. Yet I do not deny that lying is a sin.

Answer (score -1):

A muslim doesn't need to lie if he wishes to emigrate to the USA, as his freedom to do so is protected under the [first amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution) to the constitution:

> Congress shall make no law respecting an establishment of religion, or prohibiting the free exercise thereof...

This is of a piece with the principle of laicite in France, which is a judicial principle to adjudicate between religions and not to establish one as a state religion; and hence enforcing a separation between religion & state - generally it is seen as a key principle of secularism.

Although Trump is calling for ban on muslims entering the states, I see this mostly as political demagoguery without both constitutional & judicial backing; its unlikely, even as president, that he'll manage to overturn the first amendment.